# Does Wolverine feel less pain than a non-Mutant?

Tags: marvel, wolverine

### Does Wolverine feel less pain than a normal person?

So Wolverine gets shot at, stabbed and pretty much mangled at every pass. Most normal humans would pass out due to the pain. But Wolverine seems to be immune to a lot of this.

So does his mutant powers enable him to feel less pain?

Comment: http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11111/111119363/3759368-phantom.gif

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2dDPRDEfV8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a counter-intuitive, but it's the opposite.

As Valorum and Quentin posted sources to where it says he feels the pain and how he deals with it in this page:

[image]

And [This YouTube video clip from one of the X-men movies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2dDPRDEfV8)

That answers the question partially, but leaves out a key thing:

Wolverine heals perfectly and completely which means he doesn't get caluses, thicker skin, deadened nerves, etc. that a normal human would do from repeated trauma to a given region of their body. The result of this is that Wolverine not only feels the pain at the level that a normal human would, he feels it worse in most cases than what a normal human would after having been hurt in the same way he does if they got hurt and waited to be healed to do it again, because their body has less nerves and such where as his does not.

On the other hand, there are many injuries that hurt not because they are in themselves painful, but because when you have them and move your body with them it hurts. For instance, you can break a bone and not even realize it until minutes later when you have to move the arm or leg and then you feel an excruciating amount of pain. With Wolverine, because he heals so fast he would likely not feel these injuries because he heals fast enough that the pain never kicks in.

So yes and then some, and also no. It depends on the circumstances. And you'd get really counter-intuitive situations if you started thinking about them. For example: Very hot fires won't hurt him at all, because the fire is hot enough to destroy his nerves, but lower heat fires would hurt worse because they're not destroying the nerves and you're always getting a fresh burn rather than a burn through charred skin.

Comment: I don't understand. Humans without healing abilities suffer more in 2nd degree wounds compared to 3rd as well. I guess we agree on that wolverine feels pain, but he probably feels it like any regular person. Some people do not suffer much from deadly injuries because they die, and since wolverine wouldn't die easily he would suffer the pain throughout the whole healing process.

Comment: @C.Koca Maybe a bad example. Any sistuation where you are dealing with a continuously inflicted damage that doesn't just over destroy your nerves/skin, Wolverine with feel more pain than a normal person and above and beyond that level of pain due to his non-callused skin being apt to be more painful.

Comment: Maybe his nerves sometimes repair faster than the rest, which allows him to feel everything? I am just conjecturing.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2dDPRDEfV8 this might also help.