# Why does Wolverine, in-universe for the x men movies, have such a high pain tolerance?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine

Wolverine *in the movies* is hit with knives, blades, bullets, blunt objects, and even the phoenix force. Wolverine can survive all of these injuries because of his healing factor. However, as he tells Rogue, he still feels the pain.

An answer on this site, [Does Wolverine feel less pain than a non-Mutant?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/142025/does-wolverine-feel-less-pain-than-a-non-mutant/142028?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C36.9794#142028), says  that Wolverine actually feels more pain, because his nerves and flesh regenerate to their original state, thereby preventing any calluses or deadened nerve endings.

Since Wolverine cannot remember his past and he still feels all the pain of his injuries, why is he able to cope with and tolerate that level of pain?

Comment: Perhaps part of his mutation is having a higher than normal pain tolerance, as he does have superhuman senses, endurance and speed.

Comment: Speculation: in the comics, the healing factor is known of getting rid of anything that is detrimental to his health, which includes bad memories of dead loved ones. Possibly, if it does the same in the X-men movies and such, it might also be suppressing some of the pain to make it more bearable to some extent.

Comment: Further speculation: there's a wide range of pain tolerance in individuals, and Wolverine might simply be unusually tough/able to tolerate pain. Also, in nearly all continuities, he's A) rather old and experienced with combat/suffering, B) his powers require him to hurt himself (claws), and he might well have built up a tolerance, and (very speculative) C) it might well be easier to ignore pain if you know for a fact that it is only temporary and will neither debilitate you nor permanently injure/main/ you.

Comment: https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-d50513a23903e54ec1493af42868c933 - His pain tolerance is slightly better than human-normal but he mostly downplays how much things hurt and relies on mental techniques he's learned to deal with the more extreme pain from, for example, amputated limbs.

Comment: @Aaa Yeah, I remember that scene about the shot in the head for the movie. I was speaking about the comic books, where he didn't get shot in the head but his healing factor actually deleting memories so that he would stop hurting. Although I don't remember seeing any mention that his healing factor could also delete memories in the movies.

Comment: @AosSidhe - Exactly. There are people in real life who have *cut off their own limbs*. Why shouldn't Wolverine be capable of willingly subjecting himself to similar pain? He has had more practice than anyone could possibly have in reality.

Comment: He's not called "Wolverine" for nuthin'.  The legendary reputation of this northern animal is it doesn't stop, it doesn't back down–it just powers forward with fangs and claws.  Logan has such a similar ferocious focus, that someone tagged him with this nickname and everyone who later met him agreed.  Doesn't explain any particular method to ignore pain other than it being the centre of his personality for most of his life.

Answer (score 6):

Per the film's [official novelisation](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men:_A_Novelization), Logan does feel pain, but he's experienced a lot of it in his lifetime and has learned to cope with it.

> Logan watched carefully as Sabretooth moved to one of the observation
> windows in the statue’s head to watch the fireworks exploding out over
> the water. It was going to be now or never.
>
> He took a deep breath. **This was going to hurt. But pain was something
> he had experienced a lot of in the past. He would survive this.**
>
> <sub><sup>[X-Men: A Novelisation](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men:_A_Novelization)</sup></sub>

His healing factor also removes pain after just a few seconds, so even intense pain is only momentary for him, making it far more bearable.

> He pulled the one claw out and let the ripped-up arm drop into a
> natural position. He could feel the pain subside as his healing
> ability kicked in.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will be able to obtain an answer from the movies, but the movies which are based on the comic have addressed it -

> In X-Men: Unlimited #12, by Stuart Moore and C.P. Smith, Wolverine explains he can feel phantom pain from serious injuries he recovered from months after they occurred. With all the battles he’s been through the stocky Canuck must feel perpetual phantom pains. But he has developed remarkable coping mechanisms to deal with the surplus of pain he shouldereds. One handy trademark of his ability is he recovers from mental trauma by a sort of healing mind wipe where all the bad memories disappear thanks to his healing factor. So some of the awful things he has done (because he’s the best at what he does) or were done to him, are erased

He learned that -

> In the same issue mentioned above, he says he learned from a Japanese sensei to familiarize his pain, visualizing it as a physical being (like a mean, faceless monster). Then there's advice he got from a Tibetan monk to conjure up a caregiving angel—obviously Jean Grey—to protect him from the pain.

*In his own words: “You don’t have to live through this ‘til it’s over. You just have to live ‘til the next moment. You’ll deal with that one when it comes."*

[Source](https://screenrant.com/wolverine-secret-to-deal-with-pain-x-men/)

Answer (score 0):

### Pain is just an information

It is just your body saying that "Something bad is happening!". Yes, you can feel so much pain that you almost cannot function... but this is all in your brain. This means, that there are certain methods to learn how to deal with it - [you can meditate](https://lluh.org/services/neuropathic-therapy-center/blog/5-ways-take-your-mind-pain) or... you can get angry.

> Adrenaline tells your body how to reallocate resources, causing the physical responses, one of which includes the release of endorphins, neurotransmitters that act as your body’s natural painkillers. With endorphin release, **your after-accident pain may be partially or completely masked**. <sup>[source](https://www.pinnaclehealthchiro.com/blog/how-adrenaline-and-endorphins-can-delay-the-pain-you-feel-after-a-car-accident#:%7E:text=Adrenaline%20tells%20your%20body%20how,be%20partially%20or%20completely%20masked.)</sup>

I'm not sure how good Logan is on the meditation techniques, but he definitely knows how to get angry, to the point where he is sometimes dangerous to his friends.

> Wolverine has had a temper and bloodlust ever since he was introduced, with his fighting spirit and indomitable will part of what allowed him to take on the Hulk in his very first appearance. This penchant for violence is showcased especially whenever he has something to lose or he has already lost something important. For instance, seeing his teammates in mortal danger will set him off, endangering not only his enemies but anyone around him. <sup>[source](https://www.cbr.com/wolverine-wild-superpower-berserker-rage-explained/)</sup>

Nice example here:

> He is lost in some sort of berserker rage and doesn't feel pain anymore

Now, since this has been downwoted due to lack of of the movies, let me bring some examples from the movies themselves:

When Wolverine is wounded, he can definitely feel pain (at least judging by his facial expression):

[image]

In the first *X-men* movie, Magneto immobilises Logan in a such way, that the claws are facing into his own arms. You can see that Wolverine  makes a few deep breaths, preparing himself mentally before slicing his own body to free himself. He **does** feel pain, but he is prepared to take it - this would be the "meditate through pain" method.

In contrast, you can see the second way (rage) for example in the *Wolverine* movie, where he is pierced by multiple arrows:

His face is just a tranquil fury

Comment: This greatly reminds me that, in the comics, Wolverine had a tendency to lose control of his inner beast and go savage. He actually learned to meditate to better control himself. Curiously enough, when he got/lost his adamantium, he gained/lost extra self-control.

Comment: I'm very curious as to what were the reasons for this answer to be voted down. I don't seem to see anything wrong with it.

Comment: The large unsourced quote that you've culled from the Internet isn't going to help you.

Comment: @Valorum you're right, I've fixed it.